# Confused with D Latch symbol

Tags: pic, logic-gates, latch, boolean-algebra

Is this just a regular D Latch with an inverted clock or is this a D Latch with an inverted clock which becomes active on the negative flank of a signal?

[image]

Somehow I suddenly became very unsure of this and I don't know what to think.

This is the full circuit, its a buffer for the I/O pins of PortA on a PIC18F4550
[image]

I got a half complete explanation on the working of this circuit written down but I can be sure of it because I don't fully understand the working of the latch.

Comment: As depicted it is clearly understood (by me) that latch triggers at negative transition of the clock pulse, or as call it negative flank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said, this is a latch that triggers on falling edge. The data latch is used to set value of the output, the TRIS latch is used to put the output diver to high impedance state, so the pin can be used as input.

They use falling edge to change state of the two latches so you don't need to wait an extra clock tick for the changes to take effect: When you change port settings, this happens in reaction to rising edge of the clock somewhere in the CPU. The signal travels to the I/O pin logic (there is delay) and gets registered on falling edge within the same period.

This allows the next instruction to read/write on the same port, without need for no-operation instruction in between.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it works like a normal D-latch, but triggers on the negative edge of the clock instead of the positive one, like in [this image](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/Negative-Edge-Triggering.jpg).

Edit: like Marko already said in the comments. Saw it after the answer, I agree with him!